# Not able to call function from class (Scala)

Tags: scala, function, class, methods, databricks

I am simply trying to call a method from a class (in a databricks notebook) I have created in Scala. Don't worry about all the code in between. Just focus on the `SecondExplode` class and the `registerUDF` function at the very bottom. The class is as follows:

```
case class SecondExplodeTimes(start_dt: String, end_dt: String, counter: Int)



class SecondExplode extends Serializable {
     def expandDatetimeRangeToStartAndEndSeconds(start: String, end: String, ceilingLimit: Int): Seq[SecondExplodeTimes] =
    {

      val start_time: DateTime = DateTime.parse(start, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

      val end_time: DateTime = DateTime.parse(end, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

      val secBetween = end_time.getSecondOfMinute - start_time.getSecondOfMinute

      (1 to secBetween).zipWithIndex.map{case (p, counter) => {
       val strt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").print(start_time.plusSeconds(p-1))
       val endt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").print(start_time.plusSeconds(p))
       SecondExplodeTimes(strt, endt, counter)
      }}.toSeq
    }

    def registerUDF: UserDefinedFunction = {
      val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
      spark.udf.register("second_explode", expandDatetimeRangeToStartAndEndSeconds _)
    }
}
```

#### calling the class and function in the next cell

```
val secondexplode = new SecondExplode.registerUDF
```

I am getting this error:

`error: not found: value SecondExplode. val secondexplode = new SecondExplode.registerUDF`

I believe I am using version Scala 2 so the syntax is correct. Simply put, I am attempting to call the `registerUDF` function from the `SecondExplode` class to test it actually it works. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try with parenthesis `(new SecondExplode).registerUDF`?

Comment: Or `new SecondExplode().registerUDF`

Comment: This worked. ```new SecondExplode().registerUDF``` also worked. The cell is running without any errors, but if the parenthesis is not added at the end of registerUDF, is it actually calling the function?

Comment: Yes it is. In Scala 2 parenthesis can be omitted if no arguments expected, moreover your method is not declared with parenthesis in the 1st place. With Scala 3, I believe parenthesis become mandatory to avoid confusion in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is `(new SecondExplode).registerUDF`.

The problem is with parsing precedence. The `.` has higher precedence than `new`. The compiler assumes you're trying to make a `new` instance of `SecondExplode.registerUDF`, rather than make a `new SecondExplode` and then call the `registerUDF` method on the instance.

The reason why this is a possible misinterpretation is that there's nothing that prevents you from doing:

```
object SecondExplode {
  class registerUDF {}
}
```

in which case, `new SecondExplode.registerUDF` would have worked.